# How to set a cell editable in jqGrid after the setcell method is called and values set in jqGrid cells?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a unique requirement in jqGrid. I'm using a jqGrid with data from a backend SQL Server. Everything is working fine. My problem is that I'm was using the `setCell` method in JQGrid to set some values in cells.

`grid.jqGrid('setCell', rowId, finalJsonColumnName, value);`

It's working and setting values correctly. My problem is that after setting the values in jqGrid, the particular cell became uneditable.

I don't need the cells to be uneditable after `setCell`. I want them to remain editable. I was trying to call another method to make the cells editable:

`grid.jqGrid('setCell', rowId, 'precPsProg', '', 'editable-cell');`

But it's not working. Please can anyone help me out?

Comment: There are only class `"not-editable-cell"` and no `"editable-cell"` which jqGrid use. You should describe more clear what you do, why you need to use `setCell`. You don't wrote even which editing mode you use. Is it [cell editing mode](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing)? Why you need to use `setCell` during the cell is editing. Moreover it could be that you use word "uneditable" for the cells which are **editing**? Be editable means that the cell can be editing after some additional action like click on the cell. It's not the same as be editing.

Comment: Kindly post your code for more clearance

Answer (score 0):

Despite of this is an old thread, I had the same problem when setting the value of a cell  using the `setCell` method in `JQGrid` (the cell became uneditable). After hours of searching, I found a solution, by using this:

```
document.getElementById(rowId + "_Column_Name").value = some_value;
```

This sets the value of the specific (`row`, `column`) cell, and it remains editable (being submitted to the server when saving the row).